# Why is this completion block correctly being called?

Tags: objective-c, closures, automatic-ref-counting

Why does this completion block correctly get called?

```
CompletionBlock comp = ^(BOOL enabled) {
            //enabled is being correctly set
            NSLog(@"result: %i", enabled);
};

@autoreleasepool {
    Monitor *monitor = [[Monitor alloc]initWithCompletionBlock:comp];
    monitor = nil;
}
```

The monitor will start a NSTimer to call the completion block 10 seconds after monitor is instantiated.

The monitor does have a reference to comp internally (by way of `@property (nonatomic) CompletionBlock compblock;`) but the ingredients for a circular reference don't appear to be there, as nothing is referencing monitor.

Is this normal behavior? And is it behavior I can count on? It really doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of the Monitor class, we can't really give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the `Monitor` instance is the target here.  `NSTimer` retains its target in order to avoid a crash caused by messaging a deallocated object when it fires.* The current run loop retains the timer when it's scheduled.

This is normal behavior, and [you can rely on it](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimer/1412416-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval?language=objc):

> **target**
>   The object to which to send the message [...] The timer maintains a strong reference to `target`...

In fact, you must take it into consideration so that you don't create a retain cycle between the timer and its target.

---

*`NSTimer` predates auto-nilling weak references by a long time.

Comment: You are correct, the Monitor object is the target. I'm also using repeat:NO. The documentation states that once the timer fires it will be invalidated. I'm guessing that means after the selector completes? Otherwise there would be a chance that GC could do it's thing too soon.

Comment: Yes, the timer won't invalidate itself until after it's told its target to perform the selector.